# My gray cat won't let me pet her unless I'm talking to her she will also let me pet her kittens why

Tags: cats, behavior

My gray cat is very lovely but I can't pet her unless I'm talking to her. She will only let me pet her for a little bit of time but will strangely let me play with her kittens. I want to pet her for a longer time and not have to talk to her to pet her. What should I do?

Comment: Cats also have personalities, some cats lean towards being all about affection and human interaction, while other cats prefer to have it in smaller dosages. Usually a cat will let you know where the line of interaction is drawn, and when/where it wants to be pet/scratched.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe your cat is more sensitive to petting. My cat only tolerates scratches. Any kind of petting will cause her to roll over and show me her tummy and if I touch her there I will get bitten.

Maybe instead of talking to her, always approach her quietly and let her smell your hand first. And let her show you where she wants you to pet her(Usually around her head area)? I think for a cat petting their body doesn't do much for them or they don't know how to enjoy those.